# how to get absolute value of a number in java using bit manipulation

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, absolute-value

I want to implement a function to get the absolute value of a number in java: do nothing if it is positive, if it is negative, convert to positive.

I want to do this only using bit manipulations and no number comparators.

Please help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well a negation:

```
-n
```

Is the same as the two's complement:

```
~n + 1
```

The problem is here you only want to negate if the value is < 0. You can find that out by using a logical shift to see if the MSB is set:

```
n >>> 31
```

A complement would be the same as an XOR with all 1's, something like (for a 4-bit integer):

```
~1010 == 1010 ^ 1111
```

And we can get a mask with the arithmetic right shift:

```
n >> 31
```

Absolute value says:

- if n is < 0, negate it (take the complement and add 1 to it)
- else, do nothing to it

So putting it together we can do the following:

```
static int abs(int n) {
    return (n ^ (n >> 31)) + (n >>> 31);
}
```

Which computes:

- if n is < 0, XOR it with all 1's and add 1 to it
- else, XOR it with all 0's and add 0 to it

I'm not sure there's an easy way to do it without the addition. Addition involves any number of carries, even for a simple increment.

For example 2 + 1 has no carry:

```
10 + 1 == 11
```

But 47 + 1 has 4 carries:

```
101111 + 1 == 110000
```

Doing the add and carry with bitwise/bit shifts would basically just be a loop unroll and pointless.

(Edit!)

Just to be silly, here is an increment and carry:

```
static int abs(int n) {
    int s = n >>> 31;
    n ^= n >> 31;

    int c;
    do {
        c = (n & s) << 1;
        n ^= s;
    } while((s = c) != 0);

    return n;
}
```

The way it works is it flips the first bit, then keeps flipping until it finds a 0. So then the job is just to unroll the loop. The loop body can be represented by a somewhat ridiculous compound one-liner.

```
static int abs(int n) {
    int s = n >>> 31;
    n ^= n >> 31;

    int c = (n & s) << 1;
    c = ((n ^= s) & (s = c)) << 1; // repeat this line 30 more times
    n ^= s;

    return n;
}
```

So there's an abs using only bitwise and bit shifts.

These aren't faster than Math.abs. Math.abs just returns `n < 0 ? -n : n` which is trivial. And actually the loop unroll totally sucks in comparison. Just a curiosity I guess. Here's my benchmark:

```
Math.abs: 4.627323150634766ns
shift/xor/add abs: 6.729459762573242ns
loop abs: 12.028789520263672ns
unrolled abs: 32.47122764587402ns
bit hacks abs: 6.380939483642578ns
```

(The bit hacks abs is the non-patented one [shown here](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerAbs) which is basically the same idea as mine except a little harder to understand.)

Comment: Nice solution. Mine still requires one comparison.

Comment: thanks. I guess there is no way to do it without mask

Comment: For giggles, I added a version without the addition.

Comment: Be aware that `Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE)` results into `-2147483648`.

Answer (score 2):

you can turn a two's-compliment number positive or negative by taking it's logical negation

```
i = ~i; // i equals not i
```

You can use the `Math.max()` function to always get the positive

```
public static int abs(int i) {
    return Math.max(i,~i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what type of number you are using. For an int, use

```
int sign = i >> 31;
```

This gets the sign bit, which is 0 for positive numbers, and 1 for negative numbers. For other primitive types, replace 31 with the number of bits used for the primitive minus 1.

You can then use that sign in your if statement.

```
if (sign == 1)
    i = ~i + 1;
```

Comment: I figured the first part, its just that i wanted to know the bitwise alternative to `i = -i`

Comment: There isn't really one. You can do i = ~i + 1, but that still isn't fully bitwise.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find that this little ditty is what you're looking for:

```
int abs(int v) {
    int mask = v >> Integer.SIZE - 1;

    return v + mask ^ mask;
}
```

It's based on [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerAbs) absolute value equation and uses no comparison operations.  If you aren't allowed to use addition, then `(v ^ mask) - mask` is an alternative.  The value of this function is fairly questionable; since it's nearly as clear as the implementation of Math.abs and it's only marginally faster (at least on a i7):

1. `v + mask ^ mask`: 2.0844380704220384 abs/ns
2. `(v ^ mask) - mask`: 2.0819764093030244 abs/ns
3. `Math.abs`: 2.2636355843860656 abs/ns

Here's a test that proves that it works over the entire range of integers (the test runs in less than 2 minutes on an i7 processor under Java 7 update 51):

```
package test;

import org.hamcrest.core.Is;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class AbsTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        long processedCount = 0L;
        long numberOfIntegers = 1L << Integer.SIZE; //4294967296L
        int value;

        for (value = Integer.MIN_VALUE; processedCount < numberOfIntegers; value++) {
            Assert.assertEquals((long) abs(value), (long) StrictMath.abs(value));
            if (processedCount % 1_000_000L == 0L) {
                System.out.print(".");
            }
            processedCount++;
        }
        System.out.println();
        Assert.assertThat(processedCount, Is.is(numberOfIntegers));
        Assert.assertThat(value - 1, Is.is(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    }

    private static int abs(int v) {
        int mask = v >> Integer.SIZE - 1;

        return v + mask ^ mask;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

## This problem can be broken down into 2 simple steps:

**1.**
If >= 0 then just return the number.

**2.**
If smaller than 0 (ie. negative), then flip the first bit that indicates that the number is negative. This can easily be done with an XOR operation with -1 and the number; Then simply add +1 to deal with the offset (signed integers start at -1 not 0).

```
public static int absolute(int a) {
    if (a >= 0) {
        return a;
    } else  {
        return (a ^ -1) + 1;
    }
}
```